# Inconsistency of Booleans from the same method

Tags: java, android, methods, boolean

I have a boolean in a class that controls gameplay called load. If it on the main menu the user clicks 'NEW', the class is created, and load is set to false, so the game does not load a save, and vice-versa. This is how the class is created and load is set:

```
GameScene gameScene = new GameScene();
gameScene.setLoad(load);
System.out.println("LOAD SET TO"+load);
setScene(gameScene);
```

the boolean 'load' is in the constructor of the method that this code is in. Anyway here is the initialization of 'load' in my GameScene class:

```
    public boolean load;
```

This is its setter:

```
public void setLoad(boolean load) {
     this.load = load;
}
```

And its getter:

```
public boolean isLoad() {
    return load;
}
```

This is very simple and it seems like it would work fine. It, however, does not. I have this continuously run:

```
System.out.println(isLoad());
```

Now, this accurately shows the boolean. But where it is inconsistent is in my method that loads a level from an XML file. This is one part of it:

```
else if ((type
                            .equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_NPC))
                            && !(isLoad())) {
                        npc = new NPC(x, y, vbom, physicsWorld) {
                        };
                        levelObject = npc;
                        System.out.println("Load is: "+isLoad());
```

This is run regardless of what load is, it seems. It is called every time and it prints that isLoad(), which has somehow been either true or false the whole time is always false.

This is very basic java, and I have no idea why the method isLoad() varies when called within a split second. Load is set once, at the creation of the class, and not touched after that. So why is this happening?

Comment: First of all, IMO, you should make `public boolean load` as `private boolean load` instead. And knowing `load` variable is a property of `GameScene` class what value are you passing when executing line `gameScene.setLoad(load);`?

Comment: From my menu class, I have a 'new' button and a 'load' button. Load passes true, new does not. That then calls the first piece of code.

Comment: Is there any threading happening here?  ex. a worker thread vs main thread accessing this class?   If so you should make the boolean volatile.

Comment: Also rename load as mLoad ;)

Comment: Set a System.out.println in the setLoad to see what are you actually passing there. But make it private (And rename it, the Android convention is to use mLoad) (which I don't really like but it's all about consistency)

Comment: Okay. I used mLoad, added some more printlns, and everything is right, except my level loading method. (The last piece of code).